# ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir

Tags: webpack, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am new in `NativeScript`, I tried to run my HelloWord app using `NativeScript` and `Angular`. I connected my android device and then i run command `tns run android` its how me following error.

```
Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\runtimeDir11923-7308-1ed73lj.8p03\framework\app\libs\runtime-libs'                          at Object.fs.rmdirSync (fs.js:846:18)

at rmkidsSync (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:247:11)

at rmdirSync (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:237:7)

at fixWinEPERMSync (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:150:5)


at rimrafSync (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\temp\node_modules\rimraf\rimraf.js:216:26)    
at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\temp\node_moules\rimraf\rimraf.js:245:5
```

Whats wrong with me? Can you help please ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to run it with admin privileges, inside project folder do `//in the search bar type
cmd then on cmd right click and select run as administrator then cd /yourProjectDir 
 if you are on win10, then in your project folder on the top left look for the cmd(terminal) icon the one black and one blue, click the blue one andrun tns run android`

Answer (score -1):

Inside the folder node_modules, remove the folder **.domelementtype.DELETE** manually or cut it and past out off the project

Comment: Altering node_modules files is not a good practice.